# Automake: configure subdirectory only

Tags: makefile, autotools, configure

This concerns an external project, where one *OneLibrary.c* and *SomeLibraries.am* where modified;

It would be nice to
 `./configure --please-configure-only-this-subdirectory=./SomeLibrariesSubdirectory`

something similar to `make -C ./SomeLibrariesSubdirectory`

Because the whole "./configure" takes 5 minutes when only two lines have been modified ;)

Comment: Why re-configure anything if all you've done is modify one file?  Just run make again.  It should only compile what is necessary.

Comment: What @WilliamPursell said. Even if you do modify an automakefile or `configure.ac` that would require reconfiguration, automake writes rules (which work mostly correctly) to run the reconfiguration which `make` will run.  Only once in a great while I will have to manually invoke `configure`.

Comment: @ldav1s (and WilliamPursell) hm, this appears to work as you say, many thanks!